# I have Three simple component And this mistake is confusing :

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, frontend, react-fullstack

## **that is error:**

***useFetch__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_ is not a function
TypeError: *useFetch__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1*_ is not a function
at Home (http://localhost:3000/main.3e3087e6af6306a00ceb.hot-update.js:31:7)
at renderWithHooks (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21379:22)
at mountIndeterminateComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:24665:17)
at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25961:20)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10971:18)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11015:20)
at invokeGuardedCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11072:35)
at beginWork$1 (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30946:11)
at performUnitOfWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30193:16)
at workLoopSync (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30116:9)**

``**and that is my components :**`

> 1. 

```
import Home from "./Home";
import Navebar from "./Navbar";




function App() {

  
  return (
    
      <div className="App">
        <Navebar/>
        
        <div className="content">
          
          <Home />
          
        </div>
        
      </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

> 2. 

```
import BlogList from "./BlogList";
import useFetch from "./useFetch";



const Home = () => {


    const {error, isLoding, data: blogs}=useFetch('http://localhost:8000/blogs')
    

    return ( 
        <div className="home">
            
            {error && <div>{error}</div>}
            {isLoding && <div className="loading"> <span className="sr-only">Loading...</span><div className="spinner"></div>
                        </div>}
            
            
            {blogs && <BlogList blogs={blogs}  />}
                
            
        </div>
        
    );
}

export default Home;
```

> 3. 

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const useFetch=(url)=>{

    const [data,setData]=useState(null);
    const [isLoding,setIsLoding]=useState(true);
    const [error,setErorr]=useState(null);


    useEffect(()=>{

        fetch(url)
        .then(res =>{
            if(!res.ok){
                throw Error("could not fetch the data for that resource");
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(data =>{
            setIsLoding(false);
            setData(data);
            setErorr(null);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            setIsLoding(false);
            setErorr(err.message);
        })
        
    },[url]);

    return {error, isLoding, data};

    
}

export default useFetch;
```

`I made sure to take the correct data when useEffect, useState was in the same Home Component, but when adding component useFetch as in the code, many errors fixed it, but this tired me`